# Best way to unit test JAX-RS Controller?

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, jax-rs

I am learning the library `javax.ws.rs` so I wrote a toy API.

For instance, I've got this `POST` method working. I've seen that there are many libraries for testing, like Jersey or Rest Assured, but, how can I unit test that response code is `200` and that the content is `"hello"`?

```
 @POST
     @Path("/getFoo")
     @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
     Foo getFoo(@BeanParam final Foo foo)
    {
            return new Foo("hello");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For Jersey web services testing there are several testing frameworks, namely: Jersey Test Framework (https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.17/test-framework.html) and REST-Assured (https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured) - see here a comparison/setup of both (http://www.hascode.com/2011/09/rest-assured-vs-jersey-test-framework-testing-your-restful-web-services/).

```
package com.example.rest;

import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.expect;
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;

public class Products{

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        RestAssured.basePath = "http://localhost:8080";
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetProducts(){
        expect().statusCode(200).contentType(ContentType.JSON).when()
                .get("/getProducts/companyid/companyname/12345088723");
    }

}
```